# XPath - Get table if child is not specific string

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

its posible to do that? Get all table "tr"s except the tr that have an elemente with an especific string.

Example:

```
<div class="span5">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Apple</th>
                <td>Red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Banana</th>
                <td>Yellow</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Potato</th>
                <td>Brown</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Simple example, a table with 2 columns, I can select the table with the next Xpath:

```
//div[@class='span5']/table[@class='table']
```

But its posible to select the table WITHOUT the "tr" that contains:

```
//th[.='Potato']
```

Im usualling solving that problem geting all the table and then filter "tr" contents in Python, but I want to filter with XPath and optimize a bit my code without charge it in memory.

Thanks

Comment: `//div[@class='span5']/table[@class='table']//tr[not(th[.='Potato'])]`

Comment: Thanks splash58, your XPath didnt works, get all the elements, but you help me!!
This is working
    
    //div[@class='span5']/table[@class='table']//tr[./th[.!='Potato']]

Comment: at least, it works on xpath testers, for examlple, there - http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the answer. If you found the answer yourself, _post_ it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - and [self-accept](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath can be a bit simpler, like so :

```
//div[@class='span5']/table[@class='table']//tr[th != 'Potato']
```